# outlook 2007: adding new employees automatically/programmatically?

Tags: .net-framework, winforms, vba, microsoft-outlook

we have about 300 employees and we are hiring like crazy. is it possible to programmatically add new contacts to every employees' address books as new hires come in?

Comment: @moderator please move this to serverfault

Comment: zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz

Answer (score 1):

Kinda off topic, but are the users not created in your Exchange organization? If they are then they will be part of your global address list.

Comment: @dustin i dontknow its a good point

Comment: You have to have an email server of some sort. Usually large Outlook organizations are running on Exchange. You would have better luck on http://serverfault.com

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible. Usually this sort of thing is called "[provisioning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Provisioning)" (1). There are a [lot of commercial products](http://www.gartner.com/technology/media-products/reprints/oracle/article157/article157.html) out there that do this (2). Microsoft's product (now called [Forefront Identity Manager](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forefront_Identity_Manager) runs about $15k for the server license.

If you're using Exchange, you should be able to add them once to the global address book and then all the employees end up with the update.

Notes:
1 - with "deprovisioning" being the term for turning off access when folks get fired.
2 - before there were commercial apps that did this, I once wrote an in-house app to automate what could be automated (add them to active directory and email, etc) and print out a checklist for the things that couldn't be automated (give them a key, or take it away, etc). This way, the HR person typed the details in once and only once so that all the systems had the same name and details.